# DXA 1.7: Webapps BinaryData nesting infinite folders problem

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa-1.7

I tried deploying my DXA 1.7 java webapp to one of our customer servers yesterday. Im experiencing strange folder nesting inside the ROOT webapps BinaryData folder.

See this image:
[image]

It should be:
`BinaryData/1264/en/system/config/*`

But somehow the webapp creates:
`BinaryData/1264/en/en/en..../system/config/*`

Everytime i call `/admin/refresh`, it adds additional `/en/en/en` to the fodler structure.

The resulting exception is that the DXA webapp cant find our entity types.

> 09:44:14.933 [ajp-nio-16019-exec-3] ERROR c.s.w.c.i.m.ViewModelRegistryImpl - Cannot determine entity type for semantic schema names: '[http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:DefaultMultimediaSchema]'. Please make sure that an entry is registered for this view name in the ViewModelRegistry.
>   09:44:14.933 [ajp-nio-16019-exec-3] ERROR c.s.w.c.controller.PageController - Exception while processing request for: /en/

The webapp is running without problems on two development environments. The only difference here is that we now have a loadbalanced system. I already tried shutting down all nodes exept for one for better debugging the issue but i had no success yet. I did double and triple check the Topology Manager setup but i cant see any problems there.

[image]

EDIT:

If i stop the web application and just call the baseurl with `/en/`, it creates `BinaryData/en/en/en/system/*`, if i then call `/en/admin/refresh`, it creates `BinaryData/en/en/en/en/en/en/system/*`

[image]

Comment: If you stop the web application and empty the entire `BinaryData` folder, does it work the first time? Maybe you can **edit** your question and add a few more details about the reproducible scenario with `admin/refresh` and the creation of the nested folders?

Comment: Added an additional error description for the admin/refresh

Answer (score 1):

We found the solution by try & error. The problem is that we switched to different databases for `Broker`, `Discovery` and `Deployer State`.

Dev Server setup where it was working all time:

- SDL Content > Broker DB `DEV_INTRA_CD_BROKER`
- Discovery Service > Broker DB `DEV_INTRA_CD_BROKER`
- Deployer State > Broker DB `DEV_INTRA_CD_BROKER`

Test environment had different setup due to load balanced environment

- SDL Content > Broker DB > `TST_INTRA_CD_BROKER_LIVE`
- Discovery Service > New own DB > `TST_INTRA_CD_DISCOVERY_LIVE`
- Deployer State > New own DB > `TST_INTRA_CD_STATE_LIVE`

This setup was mentioned by SDL with a reference to this guide:
http://blog.trivident.com/using-sdls-microservices-in-a-web-farm/

This setup however caused the problem with the `/en/en/en` folders. I switched the `Discovery` and `Deployer State` databases back into the `Broker DB` and ran the discovery registration tool again to register the capabilities in the `Broker DB`.

Republished my site and DXA settings and the error was gone.

Weird error that makes no sense, maybe its a bug in the DXA/DD4T framework, i cant tell.

Comment: This is a really odd one. If you can reliably reproduce, I'd consider reporting it to SDL.